# How to handle content:// Uri in order to open a file

Tags: android, url, android-contentprovider

I'm using the Android's `DownloadManager` class. It returns `Uri` with `content://` scheme after clicking on the "downloaded file" notification. I have a method which is now only able to open files using file Uris (with "file" scheme). What is the easiest way to get the `File file` from the content Uri. Any examples are welcome.

```
public PlsReader(URI path) {

   File file = new File(path);
}
```

Comment: if i give u absolute path from URI then can u open this dude

Comment: How can I get this absolute path?

Comment: i give u method see my answer

Comment: I don't see any answer yet :). edit: now I can see.

Comment: so so prob has been solved ?

Comment: No, it hasn't because the downloaded files in this case aren't images. And your solution will work only for images.

Comment: see my edit answer once

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try this 
1st method to get is below

```
Uri.getPath();
```

this will give u whole absolute path of any file

and 2nd method is below

```
  Strinf absolutepath =   getRealPathFromURI(this,URI);
```

and method getRealPathFromURI is here

```
  public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
      Cursor cursor = null;
      try { 
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
      } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
          cursor.close();
        }
      }
    }
```

then pass this absolutepath string to your file like this

```
public PlsReader(String absolutepath ) {

   File file = new File(absolutepath );
}
```

best of luck dude :)

Comment: there is many option in this method just search dude i only try to say that  our main goal is convert URI to absolute path and then call from absolute path in this answer i said this only

Comment: from this u got a vision how u show or open file from URI have u get my point

Answer (score 0):

Use `Context#getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` to get an InputStream from a Uri.

Or use `Context#getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor()` to get a ParcelFileDescriptor. Then use `ParcelFileDescriptor#getFileDescriptor()` to get a FileDescriptor.